# Ember: willTransition() in route breaks link-to helper active class

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebarshelper

After adding this action to my Route:

```
  actions: {
    willTransition() {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
```

all links inside the template that reference to a nested route are marked as active, even if they produce urls with **different dynamic segments**.

I've made an Ember [Twiddle to reproduce the bug](https://ember-twiddle.com/b8a4359c028a47d6b56128535ff99677?openFiles=templates.parent.hbs%2C). It only happens with willTransition() action, not with redirect() hook. (I need to use willTransition to refresh the parent route.)

One thing to mention: on first render everything is in order. It breaks when willTransition is triggered.

Any ideas? :)

## Update

What seems to cause the issue is this.refresh() and not willTransition() action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was just because you made the fiddle quick... but the model that you are passing in as an argument should not be in quotes

```
{{link-to 'route.destination' 'Visual representation' model.thing}}
```

inline vs block // inline is always confusing... if the 'value' of the text is the defining difference... it should probably be the first argument...

```
{{#link-to 'route.destination' model.thing}}
  <span>{{model.name}}</span>
{{/link-to}}
```

https://ember-twiddle.com/702ab44ba8090a50cfabda353cffc599

This slightly more built out fiddle shows that it works properly... I think... let me know. : )

EDIT: I see what you're doing with the segments... and leveraging the defaults - but there is also this error: `/paternt' did not match any routes in your application`

I'm starting to think that this behavior is normal. They are all active because you are in a default `parent.sibling.index`

I suggest you set things up to be like this, and then see if the issue persists

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('parent', function(){
    this.route('child-list' {path: '/'});
    this.route('child-detail', {path: ':thing'});
  })
});
```

(I keep trying to fork your twiddle - but it just redirects to my fiddle... whacky stuff)

Comment: thank you for your time :)! Yep as you noticed I wasn't trying to pass models to build the dynamic segment from it. I'm passing the dynamic segment value directly with a string. 'seg1', 'seg2', 'seg3'.. (where 'seg' == segment). Couldn't find the other error you mentioned, but I polished the twiddle a bit more ;).